# using a loop, while using a variable to set how many times it loops

Tags: python, loops

```
def searchQueryForm(alist):
noforms = input("how many forms do you want to search for") 
for i in range(noforms):
    searchQuery = [ ]
    nofound = 0 ## no found set at 0
    formname = input("pls enter a formname >> ") ## asks user for formname
    formname = formname.lower() ## converts to lower case
    for row in alist:
        if row[1].lower() == formname: ## formname appears in row2
            searchQuery.append(row) ## appends results
            nofound = nofound + 1 ## increments variable
            if nofound == 0:
                print("there were no matches")
                return searchQuery
```

i am trying to use a variable to set how many times a loop occurs. i have tried to set it by entering a variable. but i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: This is where posting the full traceback of the error helps. Your error is not involved with `nofound`, but it is actually involved with `noforms`.

Comment: You don't improve your question by deleting all the code. You improve it by posting the traceback, as requested.

Comment: If the answer is ok, please, accept it @Rasnaam Tiwana

Answer (score 1):

Cast the user input. Then you will get an `int` instead of a `string`:

`noforms = int(input("how many forms do you want to search for"))`

Answer (score 0):

In `python3` use: `noforms = int(input("tldr"))` so You will get value as a `int`, not a `string`

Answer (score 0):

Cast the input to an `int`. `input` returns a string in python3.

```
int(input("how many forms do you want to search for") )
```

Your error is from passing a str to `range`

```
In [1]: range("100")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5ca20de8d687> in <module>()
----> 1 range("100")

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an i
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how you code looks, but it might be something like this:

```
var1 = "33"
for i in range(var1):
    print(i)
```

If that is the case, remove the quotation marks "" from the number, so it looks like this.

```
var1 = 33 #Quotation marks removed
for i in range(var1):
    print(i)
```